# Is it possible to redirect a http request to different server in runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, amazon-rds, adonis.js

I'm planning to use [Amazon Read Replica](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/features/read-replicas/) to replicate my database server and then split the requests to my server.

Whenever a READ request arrives, API should send/redirect to the replica
and when it's WRITING request, goes to the other server.

I'm using AdonisJS and I'm already able to check the request method using a `middleware`.
Now would be possible to change the server that request should go?

First thing I tought about changing the `.env` file, but I don't think that would be a good idea or even possible, since more than one project would access this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be very specifically how to configure a read replica with AdonisJS.

The [documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/introduction#readwrite-replicas) states:

> AdonisJS supports read/write replicas as first class citizen. You can configure one write database server, along with multiple read servers. All read queries are sent to the read servers in round-robin fashion and write queries are sent to the write server.

Comment: I guess I couldn't express myself properly.  Thanks for the reply, sir!  I didn't want any code doing the whole thing for me. I just wanted a little light if it was possible and ways to start. But you helped me a lot. THank you! Unfortunately I'm using legacy version of Adonis and I couldn't find anything about replica in V4.0. THat is why I thought about using MIddleware or maybe create more another connection inside `database.js`

Comment: I'm sure you could do the same thing yourself by creating two different connection objects, one for the primary write server, and the other for a read replica, and direct requests accordingly.